# Detect index.html length size for iPhone 4s and iPhone 5 using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iphone

Is there a script that I can use to detect a length size for iPhone 4s and iPhone 5 using JavaScript so I can use two index.html for iphone4s and iphone 5?

When using the app the iphone automatically detect iphone 4s or iphone 5 the choose a correct index.html

This is not a launch page I'm talking about as I've

This is for iPhone app and I'll be using HTML5, CSS3 and JS (cordova 2.1 formerly Phonegap).

Comment: javascript runs on the client. you'd probably want to to this sort of thing on the server so you don't force users to download one page, just to be redirected to another.

Comment: Probably want to rethink your strategy...

Comment: Ok how do I make it work without using JS but on a server. Is there a way that I can make it work e.g. server or Xcode?

Comment: You need to use server-side scripting for that. I'd recommend PHP.

Comment: Ok, do you have sample of PHP?